# SOAP request from WSDL in .net

Tags: .net, soap, wsdl

I would like to get a sample SOAP Request for a given action from the WSDL just like SOAP UI. I would like to avoid using svcutil to generate an assembly and reflect over it, but is still acceptable. But, I am not sure how to generate SOAP Reqest from the method info.

Any info on this would be of great help.

Story behind what I need....

I am looking at a web application, which can test web services (just like wcfTestClient and SOAP UI but its web based) and user can save the SOAP Request in their account and execute them when ever they would like to as well as do it periodically.

Comment: I would like to program it and generate requests from my app.

Comment: I really can't understand. You don't want to use svcutil, SoapUI. What you wanna do? Just to view the xml requests?

Comment: @armandomiani - I have edited my question to provide more clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I stumbled upon a codeproject app available at http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/wsdlparser.aspx

This meets my requirements to parse and construct SOAP Request from the wsdl just like SOAP UI. I have to make some modifications to the code, to make it work with WCF services, which I soon hope will be posting in github.

Answer (score 1):

If I get it right you can use [WCFTestClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb552364.aspx) also have a loot at [Web Service Studio](http://webservicestudio.codeplex.com/).

**EDIT** Based on your comments seems you need dynamic client proxy. Actually there are very few cases when you really need it. Can you please let us know why exactly you need it ?
Although if you are sure that there is no other way and you have one of those very rare cases so that dynamic client proxy must be used, have a look [HERE](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/Project/Download/FileDownload.aspx?ProjectName=netfxsamples&DownloadId=3939) and [HERE](http://wcfdynamicclient.codeplex.com/).

Comment: I have seen both these apps, but they try to reflect it over the proxy which was generated. I am not able to follow how they generate the SOAP request from the MethodInfo. Also, I am looking at a web application and would like to avoid reflection.

Comment: Incognito - I have edited my question with the usecase. The application is a web based service tester which can send a SOAP Request and display the response along side. I am using Plain old WebRequest to send the SOAP Request and see what is the response. Now, I would like to add a feature, where once the user clicks on the method, they would see the sample soap request just like SOAP UI. Dynamic proxy, I believe will be able create a proxy client and invoke a method from code, but not create a SOAP Request.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use SoapUI (don't see why you wouldn't) you could use the built-in [WcfTestClient.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb552364.aspx). It's primitive compared to SoapUI but could get the job done.

Comment: Well, as a part of a webapplication which will let you test webservices and lets you add more request (WcfTestClient but as a webapplication), I am looking at user giving a wsdl and choosing a method on it, I would like to display the sample request which he/she can edit further. Both, wcftestclient and SOAP UI are not exposing this functionality as API.